# custom widget on the footer

Tags: php, widgets

I'm searching a lot about custom widgets, it seems that it can be displayed just in the sidebar, but I want to display it in my theme's footer
It's just a copyright custom text that I want to add into a widget to easily change it in WP admin, I was following this tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

I have the following structure:

```
theme-folder
----includes
--------widgets
------------copyright.php


//functions.php

  include_once( 'includes/widgets/copyright.php' );

  if (function_exists("register_sidebar")) {
      register_sidebar();
  }
```

copyright.php file:

```
<?php

function register_my_widget() {// function to register my widget
    register_widget( 'My_Widget' );
}

function My_Widget() {
    $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('A widget that displays the authors name ', 'example') );
    $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'example-widget' );
    $this->WP_Widget( 'example-widget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
} 

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widget' );// function to load my widget

class my_widget extends WP_Widget {// The example widget class
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
    false,
    __( 'My Widget', 'my-widget' ),
    array( 'description' => __( 'My sample widget', 'my-widget' ) ) );
    }
}


function widget( $args, $instance ) {// display the widget
    extract( $args );
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
    $name = $instance['name'];
    $show_info = isset( $instance['show_info'] ) ? $instance['show_info'] : false;

    echo $before_widget;

    // Display the widget title 
    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

    //Display the name 
    if ( $name )
        printf( '<p>' . __('Hey their Sailor! My name is %1$s.', 'example') . '</p>', $name );

    if ( $show_info )
        printf( $name );

    echo $after_widget;
}

function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {// update the widget
    $instance = $old_instance;

    //Strip tags from title and name to remove HTML
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
    $instance['name'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] );
    $instance['show_info'] = $new_instance['show_info'];

    return $instance;
}

function form() {// and of course the form for the widget options
    //Set up some default widget settings.
    $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Example', 'example'), 'name' => __('Bilal Shaheen', 'example'), 'show_info' => true );
    $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults );

    //Text Input 
    // <p>
    //     <label for="echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' );"><?php _e('Your Name:', 'example');</label>
    //     <input id="echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' );" name="echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' );" value="echo $instance['name'];" style="width:100%;" />
    // </p>

}

?>
```

I needed to comment the html because it's not being recognized, and I don't know how to call the widget inside my footer.php, anyone have tried to do the same before?

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial it might be help you 
https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-widgets-to-wordpress-themes-footer-1033

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in widget action hook of your theme function.php

```
<?php
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Custom Footer',
    'id' => 'custom-footer',
    'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
?>
```

For Get in your theme footer widget use this code:

```
<?php
    if(is_active_sidebar('custom-footer'))
    {
        dynamic_sidebar('custom-footer');
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks Arpan, its working, how can I create as a custom input text on this custom widget in wp-admin to display the text in the widget view?